# Prove that for every x > Z > 0 f(x) < 9.5

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

It is known that for some $f(x)$, $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -10 $$

Prove that  $\exists Z > 0$ such that for $ x > Z , f(x) < -9.5 $

I'd love to hear your suggestions on how I should do this, I'm really new to calculus
and I don't really have a clue how to prove this..
Can someone show me the process of solving this?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: What does the definition of the limit tell you ?

Comment: $ \left\lvert f(x) - L \right\rvert < \epsilon  $ :\?

Comment: What is $L$ ? What is $e$ ? Be precise in your definition, what have you been taught exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x\right)=-10$ if for
every $\epsilon>0$ some $Z_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb R$ can be found such that $x>Z_{\epsilon}\Rightarrow\left|f\left(x\right)-(-10)\right|<\epsilon$.

So if $\epsilon\leq0.5$ then $x>Z_{\epsilon}\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)<-9.5$

We can take e.g. $\epsilon=0.4$. Then $x>Z_{0.4}\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)<-9.5$

Now choose some positive $Z$ that is not smaller than $Z_{0.4}$.

Comment: Can u explain me briefly why you're allowed to assume that $ \epsilon <= 0.5 $ ? that was the move I didn't know to do

Comment: According to the definition for **every** $\epsilon>0$ such a $Z_{\epsilon}$ exists. So just pick one out: e.g. $\epsilon=0.4$. Then $Z_{0.4}$ exists with... et cetera. Again, you are allowed to do it for **every** $\epsilon>0$. Also for those that satisfy $\epsilon\leq0.5$.